# Can I paint a painted concrete wall with concrete residue on it?

Tags: concrete, painting

I just had my basement concrete redone and the guys got a lot of concrete on the painted walls. I want to make sure that my paint sticks well to the concrete wall and I don't know if it's going to do that with all the concrete splatter that's there.

I can run my hand down the wall and it gets all dusty.

[image: here's the wall I'm talking about]

Answer (score 1):

Lightly brush and vacuum off the dust. Then cover the fresh concrete with a clear pre-paint sealer. When dry you can paint as you would any surface.

Comment: I would suggests "thoroughly" brush off the dust & vacuum it up. Maybe even a wipe down with a damp rag if it's really dusty. Paint that sticks to dust _will_ fall off sooner rather than later.

Comment: if you use sealer there is no dust. you have a sealed area primed for paint.

Comment: Does the sealer manage to magically make the dust stick to the wall? Even if it does, you're left with a rough paint job. Granted, OPs wall isn't the smoothest thing ever and he doesn't seem to be concerned, but on general principle...

Comment: The answer is yes. pre-paint concrete sealer is low viscosity but very sticky. It's purpose is to bind the loose particles together to the surface it is applied to and provide a proper surface to apply paint.  it's science, but I guess you could call it magic.

Comment: Adding those details into your answer (for those of us who don't know that) would make this a good answer and get my vote.

Comment: ....and just what did you believe the purpose of the "sealer" was?  There was not an explanation of what the paint does. I believe you just wish to be critical of my answer.

Comment: Yes, I chose to be critical just to be critical because I'm just mean that way. As noted in my last comment, "for those of us who don't know", because _I_ didn't know and I'd presume others don't either. Since we're now being flagged to avoid conversation in the comments, I'm out.